# PHP Connect to Remote Registry

Tags: php, connection, registry, local

I have some code that can read a key from the local registry.

```
$shell = new COM('WScript.Shell');

$data=$shell->regRead('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC\ProductVersion');
```

How can I open another computer's registry with this assuming that I have full access to that computer?

Answer (score -1):

assuming you have full access to the machine (*as you state*), simply run the code on that machine and send the results back to the other one :)